# Recursion involving Piecewise

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Student $C$ tries to define a function $G$: $Z^{+}\rightarrow Z$  by the rule
$G$($n$) =
\begin{cases}
\ 1, & \text{if $n$ is 1}\\
\ G(\frac{n}{2}),  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\[2ex]
G(3n-2), & \text{if $n$ is odd and $n>$1}
\end{cases}

for all integers $n \geq $ 1. Student $D$ claims that $G$ is not well defined. Justify student $D's$ claim.

I have no idea where to begin; please can someone point me in the right direction or perhaps hints? Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is well defined if you can follow back the chain for any input $n$ and (if there are multiple routes back) if you always get the same answer.  In this case the three pieces of the definition based on $n$ form a partition of $\Bbb Z^+$, so there is only one to apply at each time.  If you try to evaluate $G(2^k)$, you need $G(2^{k-1})$, which needs $G(2^{k-2})$ and so on and you find it is $1$, so is well defined.  But if you try to evaluate $G(3)$, you need $G(7)$, which needs $G(19)$ and you never get to a defined one, so there is not a unique value for $G(3)$

Answer (score 1):

$g(3)=g(7)=g(19)=...$, if $n$ is odd, $3n-2$ too, and if we want define $g(3)$, we have a recursion indefinite.

Comment: Thank you so very much!!!=)